# Unexplained behaviour when calculating large powers in Lua

Tags: lua, exponential

doing some exercises in Lua, I stumbled onto some (to me) really strange behaviour I just cannot explain. The following code is supposed to calculate the number of distinct terms of the form a^b for 2 <= a, b <= 100. *This* code provides the correct answer, 9183:

```
local terms = {}
local cnt = 0
for a = 2, 100 do
  for b = 2, 100 do
    term = math.pow(a, b)
    if not terms[term] then
      terms[term] = string.format("%d exp %d", a, b)
      cnt = cnt + 1
    else
      print(term .. " already in set! (" .. terms[term] .. ")")
    end
  end
end

print(cnt)
```

However, *this* code produces a different answer (only the 'print()' in the else branch is commented out):

```
local terms = {}
local cnt = 0
for a = 2, 100 do
  for b = 2, 100 do
    term = math.pow(a, b)
    if not terms[term] then
      terms[term] = string.format("%d exp %d", a, b)
      cnt = cnt + 1
    else
      --print(term .. " already in set! (" .. terms[term] .. ")")
    end
  end
end

print(cnt)
```

There. that gets me 9254 as an answer. There are no calculations done in that commented-out line, just output to the screen. Yet, it seems to influence the outcome of the calculation. Have I discovered a macroscopic system that underlies the laws of quantum mechanics? ;)

No, but seriously, I'm missing something here, and I would be thoroughly thankful if someone with more experience and knowledge could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on some Lua specific list or forum...

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. I'll wait for another day or so. If after that no one gives a more specific answer, I'll choose your answer, since it brought me some insight and a great website I can read and afterwards spread.

Comment: What version of Lua? What C compiler? What operating system? How was Lua configured and compiled ?

Comment: I'm using Lua 5.1 as a precompiled version together with "ZeroBrane Studio" (IDE) on Win 7 Professional 64 bit. So, I did _not_ compile it myself (just having a first look into it. Playing around.)

But I get what you mean. There are lots of potential causes for this behaviour. It was pretty naive to think I could calculate 100<sup>100</sup> without any problems. Well, I _was_ expecting problems, but not quite this kind of.

Comment: Both programs output the same value of `cnt` for me, using Lua 5.1.5, 5.2.4, 5.3.1 in Mac OS X.

Comment: @lhf I really don't know what's going on here. I've run both programs about 20 times, and variant 1 _always_ produces 9183 while variant 2 _always_ produces 9254 on my machine. Ô.o  
Since I'm the only one here using Windows, that might have something to do with it.

Comment: @ChristophFloat: I believe that ZeroBrane Studio uses LuaJIT as its Lua 5.1 interpreter by default. If that's the case, a call to the `print` function could prevent JIT-compilation of the `for` loops and thus cause the unexpected behavior. You can try adding `jit.off()` at the beginning to check whether that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua numbers are generally [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers. On most machines, that means practically `double` in C99 parlance which are represented by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating point numbers.

You need to read http://floating-point-gui.de/ (floating point is a headache).

In particular, Lua tables are computing some hash and testing for equality, and equality on floating point is *not* equality on mathematical real numbers. Hence using floating point numbers as key to tables is risky.

Large numbers like 98<sup>98</sup> are *not* represented *exactly* in IEEE 754...

Morally, if you use a number as a key to some Lua table, you'll better have that number be some *integer* accurately representable in IEEE754, so concretely be an integer less than 2<sup>52</sup>

I guess that you have been bitten by some implementation specific artifact. You could debug Lua C code (i.e. step by step into Lua C implementation) to find more. Perhaps some garbage collection, or simply hash table reorganization, happens in the first program, but not in the second one, or different rounding rules...

BTW, on my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 desktop with Debian packaged Lua 5.2.4-1 and with Debian packaged Lua 5.3.1-1, both programs give 9183.

Comment: Hey, thank's a lot! I was already suspecting the problem to have something to do with FPNs, but I still don't understand why the first code example _always_ gets me the correct answer while the second example _always_ gets me the (same) wrong answer.

(Great website, btw. Didn't know it, thanks!)

Comment: Choosing this answer. Together with the comments to the question, @BasileStarynkevitch, you gave me a pretty decent idea of what's happening.